# Is detecting unsigned wraparound via cast to signed undefined behavior?

Tags: c, casting, undefined-behavior

I'm using a `uint16_t` as a sequence counter in a network protocol.  This counter commonly wraps around as expected.  When a receiver gets a packet it checks this counter against the most recently received to see whether it's a new packet or an out of order packet.

Wraparound needs to be taken into account when comparing sequence numbers.  So if for example the last sequence number was `0x4000`, then a sequence number from `0x4001` to `0xBFFF` is newer, and a sequence number from `0xC000` to `0xFFFF` and from `0x0000` to `0x3FFF` is smaller.

The way I'm currently doing this is as follows:

```
uint16_t last;
uint16_t current;
...
// read in values for last and current
...
if ((int16_t)(current - last) > 0) {
    printf("current is newer\n");
} else {
    printf("current is older (or same)\n");
}
```

By subtracting the two and treating the result as a `int16_t`, I can easily see which is greater and by how much.  So for example if the current sequence number is at least 5 less that the last, i.e `((int16_t)(current - last) < -5)`, I can assume this is not due to normal packet reordering and drop the packet.

I realize that signed wraparound is undefined, however in this case I'm treating an unsigned value as signed for the sake of doing comparisons.  Does this invoke undefined behavior, and if so what would be a better way to do this type of comparison?

Comment: As long as `INT_MAX` is greater than `UINT16_MAX` (true on most 32- or 64-bit platforms) there will not be any undefined behavior, since arithmetic is done on the promoted type.

Comment: @Quentin: But if `INT_MAX` is greater than `INT16_MAX`, the operands will be promoted.

Comment: @EOF And I answered a question about that two days ago. Shame :<

Comment: If you can spare the bytes, use `uint64_t`, don't worry about wraparound, and hope to live long enough to witness your protocol wrapping around.  By a quick estimate, I think it'd take over 500 years for 1 kB packets sent at 1 gB/sec to wrap using a 64-bit counter.

Comment: Some communications devices have very limited payloads.  A lot of cheap 2.4GHz radios, for example, limit packets to less than 40 bytes total including preamble, address, and CRC.  Adding an extra six bytes of sequence number could reduce useful payload by more than 20%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour of out-of-range conversion is *implementation-defined*.

Why don't you just avoid this issue entirely and write:

```
if ( current != last && current - last < 0x8000 )
    printf("current is newer\n");
else
    printf("current is older (or same)\n");
```

Note: This answer only applies to the specific question involving `uint16_t`. For other types, different code would be required.

Comment: The trouble with your approach is that it requires the constant on the right-hand side to depend on the actual type of the unsigned variable. That's more annoying in a template and not always possible/practical in a macro.

Comment: On systems where `int` is 16 bits, `current-last` will be evaluated as `uint16_t`.  On systems where `int` is 17 bits or larger, not counting padding, `current-last` will be evaluated as (signed) `int`.  For addition and subtraction, the situation may generally be remedied by casting the sum or difference back to type `uint16_t`.  In the rare event that one wants to compute the 16 lower bits of the product of two 16-bit values which could exceed 46,340, one should first multiply one of the numbers by `1u`.  Given `uint16_t x=65533;`, the value of `(uint16_t)(1u*x*x)` will be 9, since...

Comment: ...65533u*65533 == 4294574089u, and (uint16_t)4294574089u == 9, but an attempt to perform the computation as `(uint16_t)(x*x)` or `x*x` when x is 46341 or larger may cause some 32-bit compilers to throw all concepts of time and causality out the window.  As crazy as it might seem, some compiler writers figure that since the standard allows compilers to turn `if (x < 65000) foo(x); x*=x;` into `foo(x); x*=x;`, and the latter is "more efficient", they should try to make their compilers do just that.  If one wants `if (x < 65000) foo(x); x*=x;` one must write it `if (x < 65000) foo(x); x*=1u*x;`

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure what you are talking about. "the situation may generally be remedied"  - there's nothing that needs remedying.  There's no multiplication going on here

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Arithmetic operators' promotion of short unsigned operands to signed int will *usually* not affect behavior if the results are cast back to short unsigned values, but it's important that anyone relying upon such casts be aware of cases where unwanted promotions will not affect any defined behaviors but can result in Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You may cast `uint16_t`s to `int32_t`s and do the subtracting.

```
if (((int32_t) current - (int32_t) last) > 0) {
    printf("current is newer\n");
} else {
    printf("current is older (or same)\n");
}
```

Note: when casting to `int16_t`, `uint16_t`s larger than 32767 will show up as negative (in signed integer most significant bit set to 1 means negative one, in unsigned types it's just a regular bit).

Answer (score -1):

The subtraction will take place using a promoted type unless `int` is 16 bit in which case the behaviour is implementation defined.

To be on the safe side, you could compute the absolute difference using a ternary:

`current > last ? current - last : last - current`

Comment: C11 draft standard: `7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types 1 The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N , no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.[...]`

Comment: `current - last` can never be undefined

Comment: @EOF: realised that, edited out my waffle, invalidated your comment, but could still be wrong about 16 bit int

Comment: @MattMcNabb: what happens for 16 bit int? Is it promoted to a bigger type?

Comment: @Bathsheba there is no promotion if `int` is 16-bit, because `uint16_t` does not have a range that is a subset of `int`'s range

Comment: So the result for current > last will be wrapped around? But then you get UB since you could be casting a large positive to a signed type? Do I need to go back to C school?

Comment: @Bathsheba: C11.. oh, you know by now `6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.`

Comment: @EOF: Is there anything in the Standard that would mandate that a conversion from larger types to `int16_t` couldn't peg values below -32768 or above 32767 to either -32768 or 32767, respectively?  Some hardware includes instructions that work like that, and while I wouldn't want a compiler to work that way as a default, such behavior (if available as an option) might on occasion be useful.

Comment: @supercat: You mean saturation? Sure, that's a valid implementation-defined behavior for narrowing to a signed integer type. It's not so popular though, because narrowing to an *unsigned* integer type is defined as "repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum representable number", which is truncation for 2's complement. It's easy and conformant to do just do exactly the same for signed integers.

Comment: @EOF: Is there any concise means by which code can test whether an implementation performs all narrowing conversions via two's-complement mod reduction?  For that matter, is there a requirement that an implementation where an out-of-range cast would raise a signal at runtime must do anything in particular if an out-of-range cast is performed in a compile-time constant?

Comment: @supercat: Uh, I don't know. AFAIK, an implementation can do pretty much anything it wants, as long as it documents exactly what it does. I try to stick to sane environments, which means 2's complement/truncation, no integer trap representations, no padding bits in integer types, ieee754 floats/doubles, the works. You know, the stuff computers today *actually* do?

Comment: @EOF: Until recently, I would have thought that any sane 32-bit environment could be relied upon to evaluate `x<<32` as either yielding `x` or `0` (arbitrarily chosen) unless it was configured for pedantic mode, in which case it might trap in controlled fashion.  I would not have thought that any sane platform would interpret it as negating laws of time and causality (well, actually I still don't think any *sane* platform would do that).  If the intention of the Standard is that compilers should do things a certain way absent a good reason not to, it should say that.  Otherwise...

Comment: ...it could quite reasonably be argued that because the Standard doesn't require implementations to implement signed down-sizing coercion in a genuinely useful fashion, the requirement that it be done in a consistent fashion is a useless impediment to optimization, and since implementations are free to define behaviors in cases where the Standard does not, there's really no reason it shouldn't be UB.  Indeed, if there were a recognized category of UB where compilers have historically demonstrated a narrow range of behaviors, and compilers were strongly encouraged to abide by tradition...

Comment: ...absent a compelling reason to do otherwise, I would argue that certain narrowing conversions by assignment (as opposed to a casting) should be interpreted in the fashion that compilers have *traditionally* regarded overflow [yielding a partially-indeterminate value which may arbitrarily behave in wrapping or non-wrapping fashion, with no requirement of consistency].  Of course, if compiler writers convince the committee to make it UB, I see no reason to trust that they'd continue to abide by laws of time and causality.

Comment: @supercat: What? I have no idea where you are going with this, but to clarify a few points: 1. narrowing conversion to an *unsigned* type is precisely defined. 2. narrowing conversion to a *signed* type is *implementation-defined* 3. shift of greater or equal the bit-width of the type is *undefined*. Why are you even bringing that up? There is absolutely *no* reason to make narrowing conversion undefined. It'd be insane.

Comment: @EOF: The present Standard offers no way of indicating "I need something that needs to fit in two bytes and hold values -2147483648 to 2147483647, but I don't care whether the compiler mod-wraps values outside that range".  Given that the Standard-imposed requirement for mod-wrapping impairs efficient code generation *even in cases where it offers no benefit to applications*, and given the attitude shown in the Committee's response in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_451.htm (Defect Report 451), it would hardly seem implausible that the Committee would decide to change that.

Comment: @supercat: uh, unless `CHAR_BIT >= 16`, your hypothetical type is impossible. Also, how exactly does "mod-wrapping" impair efficient code generation? Furthermore, I see no problem looking at the defect report. C11 draft std. `Annex J.2 Undefined behavior: The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8).`

Comment: @EOF: By my reading of the defect report, the Committee is saying that even in cases where the Standard *expressly* specifies that reading an uninitialized variable of type `unsigned char` yields an unspecified value of type `unsigned char`, members feel that compilers should feel free to regard almost any attempt to use that value as Undefined Behavior.  Am I not understanding that correctly?  As for my hypothetical type, I was wavering between saying 2 bytes and -32768/32767 or 4 bytes and +/-2bill and apparently left things inconsistent.  A lot of ARM code ends up inserting useless...

Comment: ...instructions to sign-extend 16-bit values held in 32-bit registers; while the DEC Alpha was ahead of its time in using 64-bit operations for all register operations (it still supported 32-bit loads and stores) it's hardly implausible that future 64-bit architectures will follow that lead.  My point was that there are a lot of times where code needs something which can hold values as large as e.g. `int16_t` can hold, and is no larger than that type, but where code doesn't care if the compiler uses a larger register to hold it and doesn't sign-extend it.

Comment: @supercat: `[u]int_fastN_t`, `[u]int_leastN_t`?

Comment: @EOF: The semantics of "fast" and "least" types are simultaneously so poorly specified as to preclude their use in many arrays, structures, unions, or other such places where their storage format would matter, but too strictly specified to allow compilers to yield optimal code if some operations (e.g. addition) are faster on larger types and others (e.g. division) are faster on smaller ones.  Further, given `uint_fast16_t u; int32_t i;`, some compilers would regard `u+i` as signed, and some would regard it as unsigned; not exactly helpful semantics.