# What is the best method to find the difference between two unsigned 16-bit numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, c

**Introduction:**

Assume that you have two 16-bit unsigned numbers that can have values from `0` to `65535`.

Let's say we have a array `arr[2]` and it's located inside a while loop:

```
i = 0;
while(1){
  arr[i++] = Get_New_Value();
  if(i == 2)
     i = 0;
}
```

It's easy to say that this can be measured, just by changing the while loop, or reading it.

But assume that this while loop is not available for you. You only have the read rights to `arr[2]` and your goal is to find the difference between `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.

I can measure the difference by see if `arr[0] < arr[1]` then you can find the difference by `arr[1] - arr[0]`. Or if `arr[0] > arr[1]`, then you do `arr[0] - arr[1]`.

But hear now. The function `Get_New_Value();` is a counter and it counts from `0` to `65535` and then starting over again, that mean if `arr[0] = 60000` and `arr[1] = 2000`, that means the difference is `65535 - arr[0] + arr[1] + 1` because `65536` is actually `0` for unsigned 16-bit and `65537` is `1`. It all starting over.

**Problem:**

I don't know which index who have the latest updated value because `arr` gets its values inserted as it was a circular buffer.

**Question:**

Is there any way for me to find the difference between `arr` that have two index values if I don't know which index have the latest updated value?

**Additional information:**

It takes `6.5535` seconds for the counter `Get_New_Value();` to go from `0` to `65535`

**How I would solve the problem:**

I would take a value from `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` and compare it with each other. I know that it has been under 6.5535 seconds since I got these values `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.

So I just compare them

`65535 - arr[0] + arr[1] + 1` or `65535 - arr[1] + arr[0] + 1` Depending on which one is larger than the other.

Comment: The task does not have a solution. What if arr[0] = 60000 and arr[1] = 60001. Is the distance between them 1 or 65537 or 131073?

Comment: If the function that updates those variables doesn't provide the information that you need, you're stuck.

Comment: Is there a maximum difference between successive calls to `Get_New_Value`?

Comment: @dbush Sorry? I did not understand.

Comment: Why does it matter that you don't know which index has the latest updated value?

Comment: @MrYui  How much can the returned value of `Get_New_Value` change between successive calls?

Comment: @dbush It it takes 6.5535 seconds for count from 0 to 65535.

Comment: @MrYui So then the question is how many seconds can pass between each call to `Get_New_Value`?

Comment: @dbush I don't know. I don't have any information about that. Assume that you calling `Get_New_Value` at second `3` and the again at second `6`.

Comment: This is a common problem in sensor data collection. If the counter increments with a frequency of ~1Hz, you can do this easily

Comment: How often does `Get_Value` get called?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't have information about this. But it's called in between 6 seconds for sure. Or rather, fast as possible.

Comment: @MrYui. Sure you do. It may be incomplete, but do you know if it's called at least once every 18 hours? I.e., can you track the changes?

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, The `Get_new_value` is called all the time. But it takes 6.5535 seconds for the `Get_new_value` to count from 0 to 65535.

Comment: @MrYui. Does it increment once a second, or can it jump from 0 to 65535 in one shot and then sit there for an hour?

Comment: @MrYui. My point is that if you make sane assumptions about the data, this becomes doable, maybe even easy. Could you please list out all the sane assumptions you can think of in the question?

Comment: @MadPhysicist No. It runs at 10 kHz and after 65535, then it goes back to 0 again.

Comment: Remember to check the magnitude of both numbers.  `unsigned` int doesn't support negative numbers, so you may want to exchange the two numbers before subtracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that `Get_new_value` is called more often than around once every 3 seconds, that means that the value (after accounting for wraparound) will never change by more than half the range of a `uint16_t`.

Based on that, we can deduce that the most recent value is the one that the result of subtracting the other from it *and* accounting for wraparound is less than 0x8000 (or less-than-or-equal, depending on how you want to handle the boundary condition).

This check can be performed as follows:

```
if (arr[0] == arr[1]) {
    printf("no change\n");
} else if ((uint16_t)(arr[0] - arr[1]) < 0x8000)
    printf("arr[0] is more recent\n");
} else {
    printf("arr[1] is more recent\n");
```

Here are some test inputs:

```
uint16_t values[][2] = {
  { 1, 2 },
  { 0x8003, 2 },
  { 0x8003, 0x1000 },
  { 0x9003, 0x1000 },
  { 0x1000, 0x8003 },
  { 0x1000, 0x9003 },
  { 0x1, 0xffff },
  { 0x1, 0x8000 },
  { 0x1, 0x8001 },
  { 0x1, 0x8002 },
};
```

And output:

```
arry[0]=0001, arr[1]=0002: arr[1] is more recent
arry[0]=8003, arr[1]=0002: arr[1] is more recent
arry[0]=8003, arr[1]=1000: arr[0] is more recent
arry[0]=9003, arr[1]=1000: arr[1] is more recent
arry[0]=1000, arr[1]=8003: arr[1] is more recent
arry[0]=1000, arr[1]=9003: arr[0] is more recent
arry[0]=0001, arr[1]=ffff: arr[0] is more recent
arry[0]=0001, arr[1]=8000: arr[1] is more recent
arry[0]=0001, arr[1]=8001: arr[1] is more recent
arry[0]=0001, arr[1]=8002: arr[0] is more recent
```

Related: [Is detecting unsigned wraparound via cast to signed undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967370/is-detecting-unsigned-wraparound-via-cast-to-signed-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Can you show some simulation values, so we are using different values and can confirm that this method works perfectly? =) I like your answer.

Comment: Here. I found an issue https://onlinegdb.com/MibiEDKR1 here

Comment: @MrYui There are some problems with how your check works.  My alternate works.

Comment: If you see here `func(50000, 65535)`. The difference is clearly `65535 - 50000`, but it can also be `50001` if `50000` is the latest counter value and `65535` is the past counter value.

Comment: @MrYui That's where the assumption comes in that calls to `Get_new_value` are never more than 3 seconds apart, or more precisely 32768 clock ticks apart.  Otherwise there's no way to tell which is more recent.

Answer (score 1):

You said `Get_new_value` is called in between 6 seconds for sure. Then nothing is easier:

```
(arr[1] < arr[0]) ? 65536 - arr[0] + arr[1] : arr[1] - arr[0];
```

---

```
i = 0;
while(1){
  arr[i++] = Get_New_Value();
  if(i == 2)
     i = 0;
}
```

is too long. I would do it like

```
for (int i = 0; ; i %= 2)
  arr[i++] = Get_New_Value();
```

I assume the array is `uint16_t arr[2];`. I would modify it like

```
uint16_t arr[2][2]:
for (unsigned uint16_t i = 0; ; i++)
  arr[i / 2][i % 2]  = Get_New_Value();
```

---

After all comments I would make `a[1]` to be always the recent value:

```
while (true) {
  a[0] = a[1];
  a[1] = Get_New_Value();
}
```

Comment: But what if arr[1] < arr[0] but arr[1] is the latest value?

Comment: It's not important what value is the latest one. The distance does not change. If you care of it, change the loop: `arr[0] = arr[1]; arr[1] = Get_New_Value();`.

Comment: What is not correct? The distance is correct after "overflow" by the module 65536. Why have you swapped the order of the arguments in the expression?