# What is the data type of the difference between two unsigned integers?

Tags: c, types, language-lawyer

I've always taken this for granted before, but suppose I have:

```
uint8_t a;
uint8_t b;

if ((a - b) < 0) {
  ...
}
```

What is the data type of the expression `(a - b)`?  [Mr. Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5hrbosvoE) tells me that it's a signed value; is that guaranteed by the any of the C specifications?

### AMENDMENT:

I now understand that type promotion will guarantee that `(a-b)` is an int when a and b are smaller than ints.  What if instead `a` and `b` are `unsigned int`s?

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned int b;

if ((a - b) < 0) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Comment: @Bob__: thanks for the reference, but -- as you see in my amended question -- the expression won't be promoted if a and b are already full integers.

Comment: `uint8_t` is guaranteed to be narrower than `int`. `unsigned` is guaranteed to be the same width as `int`. `uint32_t` is *probably* the same width as `int`, but it could be narrower (if `int` is, say, 64 bits) or wider (if `int` is, say, 16 bits). Promotion rules are defined in terms of `int` and `unsigned int`; the width relationship of `[u]intN__t` vs. `int` is implementation defined.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for the clarification.  I really should have initially asked my question using uint32_t rather than uint8_t, since that's what my application is really using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This expression will have type `int`, which is signed.

Because both operands have a type smaller than `int`, both will be promoted to type `int`, and the result will have type `int`.

Integer promotions are defined in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or
> `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>   the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
> by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`;
> otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the
> *integer promotions.* All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

So this means the expression `((a - b) < 0)` could potentially evaluate as true.

Had the variables been defined like this:

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned int b;
```

Then there would be no promotion and `a - b` would have unsigned type, meaning `((a - b) < 0)` would always be false.

Comment: Ah!  I'm glad you mentioned type promotion.  My ACTUAL use case involves uint32_t values, which -- as you point out -- won't be promoted on a 32 bit system.  P.S.: I just amended the original question for your latter point.  You have saved me some astonishment -- have a check mark!

Comment: I note also that even when a and b are `unsigned int` values, `(int)(a-b)` will be treated as a signed value, so `if ((int)(a-b) < 0) ...` will be true.

Comment: @fearless_fool Yes, although the result of the conversion could be implementation defined.

Comment: @fearless_fool Casting an `unsigned int` back to `int` has some implementation-defined (and perhaps undefined) aspects.  While it will probably always work for you, why not write `if(a < b)`, which is guaranteed to work no matter what?

Comment: @SteveSummit: `if (a < b) ...` is exactly the wrong thing if either a or b is subject to rolling over (which in my case, it is...).  But I take your point about not casting -- I can assign the difference to a signed int so the compiler with `-Wall` can warn me if needed...

Comment: @fearless_fool If it's unsigned wraparound you're looking for, you probably want `a - b > 0x80000000`, assuming 32 bit values.

Comment: @fearless_fool See my question on that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967370/is-detecting-unsigned-wraparound-via-cast-to-signed-undefined-behavior